# call custom event dynamically on jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a plugin with the following structure:

```
(function($){

  function pluginName(el, options) {

    var _this = this;

    _this.defaults = {
      someOptions: '',
      onSlideStart: function() {},
      onSlideEnd: function() {},
    };

    _this.opts = $.extend({}, _this.defaults, options);

    $(el).on("slideStart", function() {
      _this.opts.onSlideStart.call();
    });

    $(el).on("slideEnd", function() {
      _this.opts.onSlideEnd.call();
    });
  }

  pluginName.prototype = {

    someFunctions: function() {
    }

  };

  $.fn.pluginName = function(options) {
    if(this.length) {
      this.each(function() {
        var rev = new pluginName(this, options);
        rev.init();
        $(this).data('pluginName', rev);
      });
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

If I call it the following way, everything is okay:

```
$('.element').pluginName({
  someOptions: 'full',
  onSlideStart: function() {
    console.log('slideStart!');
  },
  onSlideEnd: function() {
    console.log('slideEnd!');
  },
});
```

But I want to dynamic load the custom event handler like this:

```
(function($){

  function pluginName(el, options) {

    var _this = this;

    _this.defaults = {
      someOptions: '',
      onSlideStart: function() {},
      onSlideEnd: function() {},
    };

    _this.opts = $.extend({}, _this.defaults, options);

    for (var optionName in _this.opts) {
      var
        optionValue = _this.opts[optionName],
        optionType  = typeof(optionValue)
      ;

      if(optionType == 'function') {
        optionNames = optionName.split('on');
        eventName   = global.lowerFirstLetter(optionNames[1]);

        $(el).on(eventName, function() {
          eval('_this.opts.' + optionName + '.call();');
        });
      }
    }
  }

  ...

})(jQuery);
```

But this does not work. When I call the plugin with the "dynamic" part, it always call the slideEnd-function. So am I doing it wrong or is it just impossible with my plugin-pattern to call the custom event-handler dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use eval ? It's usually bad to use eval.

```
if(optionType == 'function') {
    optionNames = optionName.split('on');
    eventName   = global.lowerFirstLetter(optionNames[1]);

    $(el).on(eventName, _this.opts[optionName]);
  }
```

Try it and let me know.